# How to import photos to iPhone without getting unable to delete them?

Tags: photos, import

I use iTunes and [AnyTrans](https://www.imobie.com/anytrans/), but the photos can’t be deleted.

Is there a program to import photos without getting unable to delete them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer). It is available for both Mac and PC.

You can easily access data and import it from your iPhone without Jailbreaking your device.